# Azure Remote Monitoring Sample Code for Arduino zero+ wifi 101

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Is there an Arduino zero+ wifi 101 example sketch for the remote monitoring solution(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-suite-connecting-devices/)?

I was able to follow the following instruction to make it work but would like to try out the remote monitoring solution 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/arduinoide-arduino-wifi101-c.md

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The remote monitoring solution in the Azure IoT Suite makes use of Azure IoT Hub at the backend to connect to devices. The instructions you followed to run the Arduino sample should get you working, as it also connects to the Azure IoT hub.

Just use the connection string of the device (which you would add as a Custom Device in Azure IoT Suite portal) and use that in the Arduino sample.